# Deleting user from Ubuntu when the user is logged in

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 .Recently I downloaded Hadoop 2.0.3 and made  a user named `Hduser` which I added and give privileged rights. Now I want to delete the user.

I used

```
sudo deluser hduser
```

But it's giving me the following error:

> Warning: group `hadoop' has no more members.  userdel: user hduser is 
>   currently logged in /usr/sbin/deluser:`/usr/sbin/userdel hduser'
>
> returned error code 8. Exiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging in as root or any other user before executing the above. And make sure HDFS is down.

Comment: I logged in as my user name and then gave the command but same error persists

Comment: Are all the HDFS and hadoop related services down?

Comment: Issue HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-mapred.sh and HADOOP_HOME/bin/stop-dfs.sh from the root user

Answer (score 0):

i had these errors too on Ubuntu 12.04 but I tried it on WEBMIN and successfully deleted the user.